# BASH script exiting out before completion

Tags: bash, expect, sigint, sigchld

I have a long bash script doing a number of things that reaches this point...

(at the end of a case statement)...

```
    {
    /usr/bin/expect << EOF
    set timeout 120
    spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$AMHOST1$DOMAIN "/opt/cert_hell.sh"\
    expect assword:
    send "$PASSWD\r"
    expect #
    EOF
    }
    ;;
    esac

    case $ADMCFG in
       ($AMHOST2)

    echo "############ Now we move on with our installation... ##############"
    echo ""
    # installation
    mkdir -p /path/to/install/directory
    cd /path/to/install/directory
    unzip /path/to/software/source.zip`
```

at this point it simply dies with no output to stdout. I ran with an strace -f and here are the relevant results:

```
    [pid  3770] +++ exited with 0 +++
    <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 3770
    rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f4a5d957d40}, {0x4438a0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f4a5d957d40}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
    --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3770, si_status=0, si_utime=6, si_stime=8} ---
    wait4(-1, 0x7fff3323ddd8, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
    rt_sigreturn()                          = 0
    read(255, "exit 0\n\n# Here we begin configur"..., 4316) = 374
    rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
    rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
    exit_group(0)                           = ?
    +++ exited with 0 +++
```

I'm not certain if this string '**read(255, "exit 0...**' is the culprit nor can I ascertain why it is exiting suddenly. It does move on and briefly attempts to perform the unzip operation before it dies. If anyone has any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that you can't have any whitespace on the ending `EOF` line. Make sure that line is not indented.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but what is "`" just next  unzip /path/to/software/source.zip ?